# Download a file via HTML response

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, download

I have a JSP describing an HTML page. When a document in a table is clicked, the document should be downloaded from a database. All local, no client/server architecture. Dute to the particular architecture I'm using, I can only use JSP. I build the file using streams, but when I download it the file contains the JSP, not the original file content. How can I resolve this? 
    Note: I tried to download the file using href links with Javascript, but it was impossible to make it work in a simple JSP. The code part:

```
`   queryGetDoc+= "'"+submit+"'";
    resultSet2 = statement2.executeQuery(queryGetDoc);  
    File file = new File(submit);
    file.createNewFile();   
        if(resultSet2!=null){                   
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);  
        resultSet2.first();
        InputStream  is = resultSet2.getBinaryStream(1);            
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int read = 0;
         while ((read = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, read);
        } 
       response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachement; filename="+submit+suffix);
       response.setContentType("text/plain");
       response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the web host, not the JSP.  You can configure the web host to treat JSP files as java server page files or not.  My guess is that it is treating them like they were a simple resource file.

It's not that you're trying to directly load jsp files from the browser, right?  The browser doesn't handle jsp files.  It handles html files.  You could think of the jsp files as html files that the server must first convert.

I understand that you want to have everything on the same computer, but this doesn't mean that you can bypass standard http protocols.  You *still* require a server even if it is the same computer as the client.  I recommend you use [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) for this.  It's free, lightweight, and gets the job done, including proper loading of jsp files right out of the box, so to speak.

Comment: The JSP file is called by an external software. So it is compiled then executed. What should I do to get a file dowload in a proper response?

Comment: @LucianoSacco If the browser is displaying the JSP directly, then I'd have to argue that that isn't the case.  So your solution depends on this external software being configured properly.  Unfortunately it depends on this software and I can't help you further.

Comment: Sorry I'll be more specific. The JSP is compiled, it isn't simply dispayed.